# tooling_sidebar.yml collapses when accessing certain pages

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I am using Jekyll with GitHub pages (kramdown markdown) and am having issues with the sidebar collapsing when accessing certain pages within sub folders.  Been staring for a while.

Here is my .yml code:

```
- title: IQ
    output: web
    folderitems: 

    - title: Set up Git and Logging Bugs
      url: /set_up_git_logging_bugs.html
      output: web
      subfolders:

      - title: How To
        output: web
        subfolderitems:

        - title: Install IQ on a Test Machine
          url: /set_up_iq_machines.html
          output: web

        - title: Connect to an IQ Linux Machine
          url: /connect_to_linux_machines.html
          output: web


      - title: Processes
        output: web
        subfolderitems:

        - title: Run dbtest
          url: /run_dbtest.html
          output: web

        - title: SP or PL Testing
          url: sp_pl_testing.html
          output: web

        - title: MPX Testing
          url: mpx_testing.html
          output: web
```

The two pages are the last two. Clicking on Run dbtest does not collapse the sidebar.

What I have tried:

- The **show all characters in Notepad++** to ensure that there are no extra spaces
- Changed the subfolderitems under processes to subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you found in the meantime. But for everyone else, you need a '/' before the url to stop the menu collapsing.

Comment: No, I didn't, I just dealt with it as I had other priorities.